# instantly scroll tableView to indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I have to scroll tableView to indexPath immediately after my screen appears. Here is what I've tried but it doesn't work at start. It works only when tableView has loaded and then I press a button which scrolls tableView.

```
func scrollTableViewToCell() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 8, inSection: 1)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
}
```

I've also tried this but it doesn't work as I need:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println(indexPath)
    println(NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()!.last!.row, inSection: 2))
    if indexPath == NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()!.last!.row, inSection: 0) {
        scrollTableViewToCell()
    }
}
```

I've also tried this)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    scrollTableViewToCell()
}
```

Can someone tell me how to know when tableView has loaded all cells and then scroll it to *NSIndexPath(forItem: 8, inSection: 1)* ?

**UPDATE::**

Here is how I load the data to tableView:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return years.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allInfo[years[section]]!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tutionTableViewCell") as! TuitionTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    let info = allInfo[years[indexPath.section]]! as [String: String?]

    cell.monthLabel.text = months[indexPath.row]
    if info[months[indexPath.row]]! != nil {
        cell.tuitionLabel.hidden = false
        cell.tuitionLabel.text = info[months[indexPath.row]]!
    } else {
        cell.tuitionLabel.hidden = true
    }
    if info[months[indexPath.row]]! == "Nog te betalen" {
        cell.monthLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex: 0xff0000).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.87)
        cell.tuitionLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex: 0xff0000).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.87)
    } else {
        cell.monthLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.87)
        cell.tuitionLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.87)
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return years[section]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 16)
    header.textLabel.text = self.tableView(self.tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    let headerFrame = header.frame
    header.textLabel.frame = headerFrame
    header.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.54)
    header.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xf9f9f9)
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xf9f9f9)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 35
}
```

**SECOND UPDATE::**

My hardcoded data:

```
var years: [String] = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
var months: [String] = ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"]
var allInfo: [String: [String: String?]] = [String: [String: String?]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0

    allInfo[years[0]] = ["Januari": "300,00", "Februari": "300,00", "Maart": "300,00", "April": "300,00", "Mei": "300,00", "Juni": "300,00", "Juli": "300,00", "Augustus": "300,00", "September": "300,00", "Oktober": "300,00", "November": "300,00", "December": "300,00"]
    allInfo[years[1]] = ["Januari": "300,00", "Februari": "300,00", "Maart": "300,00", "April": "300,00", "Mei": "300,00", "Juni": "300,00", "Juli": "300,00", "Augustus": "300,00", "September": "Nog te betalen", "Oktober": nil, "November": nil, "December": nil]
    allInfo[years[2]] = ["Januari": nil, "Februari": nil, "Maart": nil, "April": nil, "Mei": nil, "Juni": nil, "Juli": nil, "Augustus": nil, "September": nil, "Oktober": nil, "November": nil, "December": nil]

    tableView.reloadData()
    scrollTableViewToCell()
}
```

Comment: Did you try to scroll in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: you should only call `scrollTableViewToCell()` once your table has fully loaded, eg after `[table reloadData]`

Comment: @Fonix I've tried this `viewDidLoad() { tableView.reloadData() scrollTableViewToCell() }` but it scrolls to wrong position. I want my tableView to scroll to indexPath centered on screen but it appears at the top [screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/opcsph.jpg).

Comment: @Fonix The red cell should be centered on screen.

Comment: In which method do you actually load the data for your tableview and how do you load it

Comment: @Paulw11 I've updated my question, take a look please.

Comment: What I meant was where /how does the data to into the arrays you are using ie `allInfo`?

Comment: @Paulw11 just hardcoded in viewDidLoad() for now.

Comment: As @dasdom suggested you should scroll in `viewDidAppear` (or possibly in `viewWillAppear`)

Comment: @Paulw11 I've updated my question with my data.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried to scroll in both viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear, the same result as on screenshot above appears(.

Comment: Strange.  I created a simple app with your code.  It scrolls correctly to the cell when I run the app but scrolling up is very jerky as it creates the cells.  Once you have scrolled to the top for the first time then scrolling is smooth.  If I don't perform the initial scroll then scrolling is also fine

Comment: @Paulw11 Your said that the tableView scrolls to the red cell centered in the screen? I've also get a bit lag when scrolling up, do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a search button at the navigation bar. I set `scrollTableViewToCell()` function to that button and run the project. When I scroll tableView a bit and then click on that button it scrolls tableView as needed. I don't know what is wrong with initial scroll(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have implemented the method `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

As you are scrolling the tableview directly to a row that is below cells that have never been rendered the tableview can't correctly lay out the cells if it doesn't know the size of the 'missing' cells.

Implementing this method in my test app resolved the scroll issue and the strange "flicking" I was seeing when I scrolled up.

Also, you should call `super.viewDidLoad()` in your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Oh, we have written answers in the same time!) Yes, I found that issue too. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Set a timer in viewdidload. This will solve your problem.

```
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.scrollToRowMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sure. I added a piece of snippet.

Comment: This worked for me. I previously had it scrolling in viewDidLayoutSubviews before viewDidAppear was called because I didn't want users to see the view scroll, but this simplifies that logic and works great.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @Paulw11 for helping me with my problem.

I solved it by removing these two lines of code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
```

Now it scrolls as needed!

Also, scrolling lag was removed by adding scrolling animation:

```
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
```